# How do you disable XCode's ModuleCache?

Tags: ios, xcode

It's horribly buggy, and frequently corrupts projects. The larger the project, the more libraries it has ... the more likely it is to happen. Seems to be a poorly-tested feature of Xcode5.

So far, the only workaround that's worked reliably is to disable architectures (Starting with arm64) and keep rebuilding, until Xcode stops corrupting itself.

Is there a way to disable this untested feature, and make Xcode5 useable again?